# Create a directory in bash, whose name starts with - ( eg : -ROOT)

Tags: bash

How do I create a directory , whose name starts with -  (eg -ROOT) in bash ?. If we are trying so bash will treat the name as command line argument and we will get the error

```
mkdir: invalid option -- 'R'
Try `mkdir --help' for more information.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prefix the directory name with a `./` to avoid having it interpreted as an option:

```
mkdir ./-ROOT
```

Alternatively, insert the argument `--` (two dashes), which causes all arguments following it to be interpreted as file names and not as options:

```
mkdir -- -ROOT
```

Comment: Keep in mind you will may have similar problems when trying to *use* the directory, so the above techniques will be necessary then as well.